# PHP Cookie still exist after deleted

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies

I have this problem with a cookies:

```
setcookie('NAME', '', time() - 3600);
 session_unset();
 session_destroy();
```

Cookie still exist in browser and I can see the values with `print_r($_COOKIE);`
But I can't access into file content (that's right because session deleted on server side).
But why cookies still visible in a browser until I close it down?

Comment: you are setting the cookie to expire, so on the next page load it will be removed by the browser.

Comment: Which cookie? if you're tring to unset the session cookie, use `setcookie(session_name(), time() - 3600);` (never use a literal for the session name unless its as a parameter to session_name())

Comment: Yes it is session cookie and I'm not setting it up on session start and it appears automatically

Answer (score 0):

> you are setting the cookie to expire, so on the next page load it will be removed by the browser. – cmorrissey

cmorrisey is correct. In your code example, I see that you set the expiration to an hour ago. You can also use 0 to have the cookie expire at the end of the session, if that is preferred.

PHP cookie: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_setcookie.asp

Expiration field is optional. Specifies when the cookie expires. The value: time()+86400*30, will set the cookie to expire in 30 days. If this parameter is omitted or set to 0, the cookie will expire at the end of the session (when the browser closes). Default is 0

session_name()/session.name - http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php

Comment: As i said above I'm not starting this cookie at all. He appears automatically when i start a session. But i don't want to keep this data

Comment: The session name references the name of the session, which is used in cookies and URLs (e.g. PHPSESSID). It should contain only alphanumeric characters; it should be short and descriptive (i.e. for users with enabled cookie warnings). If name is specified, the name of the current session is changed to its value.

Comment: string session_name ([ string $name ] )

session_name() returns the name of the current session. If $name is given, session_name() will update the session name and return the old session name.